# Access man page for package?

Tags: linux, man

After installing the `gcc-arm-none-eabi` package on Ubuntu, I can't find the tools or the manpage even though it appears the documentation is available:

```
$ find /usr/ -iname gcc*
/usr/bin/gcc
...
/usr/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi
/usr/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info/gcc.info.gz
/usr/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info/gccinstall.info.gz
/usr/share/doc/gcc-arm-none-eabi/info/gccint.info.gz
/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8
/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8-base
/usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8-base/gcc
...
```

From above, I know there is documentation available for `gcc-arm-none-eabi`. Next:

```
$ info gcc-arm-none-eabi
No menu item `gcc-arm-none-eabi' in node `(dir)Top'.
```

And:

```
$ man gcc-arm-none-eabi
No manual entry for gcc-arm-none-eabi
```

Where do I find the documentation for the package I just installed? Or more to the point, how do I access it?

Answer (score 2):

gcc-arm-none-eabi is a doc file.  It's probably not going to have a man page.  However, the gcc command has a man page. The other files are documentation for the user or developer.  Man files are normally in directories like man/man1 or man/man2.

You will also have categories of man pages:

```
   1   Executable programs or shell commands
   2   System calls (functions provided by the kernel)
   3   Library calls (functions within program libraries)
   4   Special files (usually found in /dev)
   5   File formats and conventions eg /etc/passwd
   6   Games
   7   Miscellaneous  (including  macro  packages  and  conventions), e.g.
       man(7), groff(7)
   8   System administration commands (usually only for root)
   9   Kernel routines [Non standard]
```

If a man page is in multiple categories, you can view it like 
   man 1 gcc
   man 7 groff

Comment: Thanks David. I'm OK with standard gcc. I'm having trouble with gcc-arm-none-eabi.

Answer (score 2):

`dpkg --listfiles gcc-arm-none-eabi`

You can find the file list [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/gcc-arm-none-eabi/filelist) also. You can find that on your own by going to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com) and doing a search on the package name, then click on the list of files for the distro version you have installed.

Cross-compiler builds of `gcc` start with the architecture name as the filename; they do not start with `gcc`.

BTW, your `find /usr/ -iname gcc\*` won't find any file names that start with something other than `gcc`, such as `/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc`, which is the actual compiler frontend command you need to invoke.

As far as docs: the command line options are nearly identical to the native (presumably x86(_64)) compiler, but you can view the documentation for gcc online and see if there are any special options for ARM.

Answer (score 2):

If there are man pages in the package, set the environment var MANPATH to the root (i.e. the directory that holds man1/).

Or you can do what man does, `groff -man gcc.1 | less`. `groff` has flags where you can change the output type, namely ascii (like normal `man`) postscript, html, etc.

True FSF packages tend to have minimal man pages, and tend to use info. I personally dislike info, and find the format harder to read or grep than man - to each their own.  Maybe using an alternate reader, like `pinfo` would be helpful as well.